# Is it possible to make an machine learning algorithm, that can outperform humans in complex games with current technology?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, state-of-the-art

Would a company like OpenAi, it the "average" person be able to make a bot, using machine learning, that can outperform the best e-sport players in complex games, like PubG, with the technology we have available today? And if so: what kind of models and approach would most likely be used?

Comment: Sure, take a look at papers published in [Transactions on Computational Intelligence and AI in Games](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=4804728&year=) journal. If you employ learning, they are usually supervised and reinforcemnt.

Comment: @Media thanks for the link to the journal! Do you think a supervised learning, where it learn from game footage from an amateur (me) or by learning itself completly, using reinforced learning?

Comment: Actually I didn't understand, can you edit?

Answer (score 0):

The general algorithms would be Deep Reinforcement Learning.

One possible approach would be to collect a large number of games. Then train the agent on those games.

Another possible approach would be the agent play against itself, aka self play.